# Laravel does not show all the available results from table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am working with Laravel 8 to develop online ordering project and in this project, I want to show all the orders from `orders` table if the `status` of each order is set to `awaiting`, so here is my code:

```
public function awaiting()
    {
        $orders = Order::with('user')->where('status', 'awaiting')->whereHas('user')->latest()->paginate(20);
        return view('admin.orders.awaiting', compact('orders'));
    }
```

But now the problem is, it only shows the first result from table, however there are more than one record stored at `orders` table.

How can I fix this issue?

**UPDATE #1:**

[image]

Comment: do you have records for that user or  .if no related user then record will not fetch since you have whereHas

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes I have at least 2 records with the same user id and status of awaiting

Comment: can you show screenshot of table  to check once both table

Comment: @JohnLobo I just added it

Comment: try once removing wherhas and check will you get both record

Comment: @JohnLobo No I don't get them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234061/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-tejoslaeslio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with second record in db .It has white space `awaiting\r\n` in at the end of string .

I suggest you to create `separate table` for `status` and then `reference status id` in `order table` to avoid these type of errors

So better before saving to db trim it by defining a `Mutator`

```
   public function setStatusAttribute($value)
    {
    
      
            $this->attributes['status'] = Str::of($value)->trim();
            
    }
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator
Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-trim